# Regex | validation error

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to validate a USA mobile number, since I'm using pre-built javascript validation library I just replaced [this](http://regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=22) regex validation with the previous one which comes with the validation library.

previous validation regex:

```
"telephone":{
"regex":"/^[0-9\-\(\)\ ]{10,10}$/",
"alertText":"* Invalid phone number"},
```

This works like `2126661234` but not in USA standard.

After I changed:

```
"telephone":{
"regex":"/^[2-9]\d{2}-\d{3}-\d{4}$/",
"alertText":"* Invalid phone number"},
```

Now every entry I get an error even if I enter `212-666-1234` I really don't know what is the wrong, so I'm expecting some help.

Comment: +1 for using regexlib. Are you sure the previous version had slashes in the string? `"/.../"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape the backslashes

```
"telephone":{
"regex":"/^[2-9]\\d{2}-\\d{3}-\\d{4}$/",
"alertText":"* Invalid phone number"},
```

`/^[2-9]\d{2}-\d{3}-\d{4}$/` works only in regex literals as in

```
var r = /^[2-9]\d{2}-\d{3}-\d{4}$/;
```

When you are using strings to initialize regex, you should escape the backslashes

```
var r = new RegExp("^[2-9]\\d{2}-\\d{3}-\\d{4}$");
```

Comment: Good catch. This also explains why the original *seemed* to work; it looked like `[0-9-() ]` - JavaScript strings tend to ignore wrongly escaped characters, and `-` became literal after a range, much like `[a-z-]`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the original regex escapes the `-` sign, like this: `\-`.

I don't see you doing that in your second example.

Comment: That was inside a character class, where `-` means range: `[a-z]` vs. `\d-\d`. The regex seems ok.

Comment: @Kobi, MMRUser: The _second_ dash in example 1 is escaped with a backslash, that is not related to the range a-z. So, I'm saying that maybe your regex should look like this: /^[2-9]\d{2}\-\d{3}\-\d{4}$/